# Python Bigtable Dataflow - Can't pickle <class 'Mutation'>

Tags: python, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm writing a Dataflow pipeline using Apache beam to add large batches of rows of data to Bigtable.

- `apache-beam==2.24.0`
- `google-cloud-bigtable==2.4.0`

I have the following method used in my pipeline to create the Bigtable row(s) prior to writing to Bigtable:

```py
class CreateBigtableRow(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.column_family = settings["bigtable_column_family"]
        super(CreateBigtableRow, self).__init__()

    def process(self, usage_data, *args, **kwargs):
        row_key = BigTable.generate_row_key(usage_data, key_order)
        return [
            BigTable.create_row_and_assign_values(
                row_key, usage_data, self.column_family
            )
        ]
```

where `create_row_and_assign_values is defined as:

```py
def create_row_and_assign_values(
    cls, key: str, row: dict, column_family: str
) -> DirectRow:
    table_row = DirectRow(key.encode())
    for key, val in row.items():
        if isinstance(val, float):
            val = struct.pack(">d", val)
        table_row.set_cell(column_family, key.encode(), val)
    return table_row
```

My pipeline is as follows:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipe:
    (
        pipe
        | beam.Create(["/sample_files/*combined*"])  # reads sample csv file
        | fileio.MatchAll()
        | fileio.ReadMatches()
        | beam.FlatMap(
            lambda file: csv.DictReader(open(file.metadata.path))
        )
        | "Transform to Usage dict" >> beam.ParDo(TransformToBigtableData())
        | "Create Bigtable Row" >> beam.ParDo(CreateBigtableRow(bigtable_settings))
        | WriteToBigTable(
            project_id=bigtable_settings["bigtable_project"],
            instance_id=bigtable_settings["bigtable_instance"],
            table_id=bigtable_settings["bigtable_table"])
    )
```

The problem I'm having is I get the error

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Mutation'>: attribute lookup Mutation on __main__ failed [while running 'Create Bigtable Row']
```

when running the pipeline.  I've added steps to manually batch process the records by using the `google-cloud-bigtable` library's Bigtable `Client`, but would prefer to use the build-in `WriteToBigTable` method as it handles everything for me.

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/ingest/main.py", line 226, in <module>
    run(
  File "/app/src/ingest/main.py", line 149, in run
    (
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 596, in __exit__
    self.result = self.run()
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 546, in run
    return Pipeline.from_runner_api(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 573, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 131, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 195, in run_pipeline
    self._latest_run_result = self.run_via_runner_api(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 206, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 384, in run_stages
    stage_results = self._run_stage(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 646, in _run_stage
    self._run_bundle(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 769, in _run_bundle
    result, splits = bundle_manager.process_bundle(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 1080, in process_bundle
    result_future = self._worker_handler.control_conn.push(process_bundle_req)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/worker_handlers.py", line 378, in push
    response = self.worker.do_instruction(request)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 597, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 635, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 995, in process_bundle
    input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 221, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 354, in output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 216, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 714, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1316, in _reraise_augmented
    raise new_exn.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 571, in invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1396, in process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in receive
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 179, in update_counters_start
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 211, in update_from
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 250, in do_sample
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1371, in get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 358, in get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self.encode_to_stream(value, out, nested)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 422, in encode_to_stream
    self.fallback_coder_impl.encode_to_stream(value, stream, nested)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 262, in encode_to_stream
    return stream.write(self._encoder(value), nested)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 800, in <lambda>
    lambda x: dumps(x, protocol), pickle.loads)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Mutation'>: attribute lookup Mutation on __main__ failed [while running 'Create Bigtable Row']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your google-cloud-bigtable version is too high.

There is some movement in updating apache-beam dependencies [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/16152)

They have the same issue. Can you roll back your bigtable version to something before 2? If you run this:

```
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

It'll install the recommended version.

Comment: `pip install apache-beam[gcp]` installed the same version of gcp as the beam version (`2.24.0`).  I manually set `google-cloud-bigtable` to `1.7.0` and that did the trick.  Thank you!